# Read in array data into different sized Fortran arrays

Tags: file-io, fortran

Let's say I have a 5 x 5 array of floating points in a file `array.txt`:

```
1.0 1.1 0.0 0.0 0.0
1.2 1.3 1.4 0.0 0.0
0.0 1.5 1.6 1.7 0.0
0.0 0.0 1.8 1.9 1.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.1 1.2
```

I know this is probably a strange thing to do, but I'm just trying to learn the `read` statements better:  I want to create two  3x3 arrays in Fortran, i.e. `real, dimension(3,3) :: array1, array2` and try reading in the first 9 values by row into `array1` and the following 9 values into `array2`.  That  is, I would like arrays to have the form

```
array1 = 1.0 1.1 0.0
         0.0 0.0 1.2
         1.3 1.4 0.0

array2 = 0.0 0.0 1.5
         1.6 1.7 0.0
         0.0 0.0 1.8
```

Next I want to try to do the same by columns:

```
array1 = 1.0 1.2 0.0
         0.0 0.0 1.1
         1.3 1.5 0.0

array2 = 0.0 0.0 1.4
         1.6 1.8 0.0
         0.0 0.0 1.7
```

My "closest" attempt for row-wise:

```
program scratch
  implicit none

  real, dimension(3,3) :: array1, array2
  integer :: i

  open(12, file="array.txt")

 !read in values                                                 
  do i = 1,3
        read(12,'(3F4.1)', advance="no") array1(i,:)
  end do

end program scratch
```

My questions:

A. How to advance to next record when at the end?

B. How to do the same for reading in column-wise?

C. Why is `'(3F4.1)'` needed, as opposed to `'(3F3.1)'`?

Answer (score 0):

because of the requirement to "assign by columns" i would advise reading the whole works into a 5x5 array:

```
 real tmp(5,5)
 read(unit,*)tmp
```

(note no format specification required)

Then do the assignments you need using array operations.

for this small array, the simplest thing to do seems to be:

```
real tmp(5,5),flat(25),array1(3,3),array2(3,3)
read(unit,*)tmp
flat=reshape(tmp,shape(flat))
array1=reshape(flat(:9),shape(array1))
array2=reshape(flat(10:18),shape(array2))
```

then the transposed version is simply:

```
flat=reshape(transpose(tmp),shape(flat))
array1=reshape(flat(:9),shape(array1))
array2=reshape(flat(10:18),shape(array2))
```

If it was a really big array I'd think of a way that avoided making an extra copy of the data.

Note you can wrap each of those assignments in `transpose` if needed depending on
how you really want the data represented, eg.

```
     array1=transpose(reshape(flat(:9),shape(array1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading by line is easy :

```
READ(12,*) ((array1(i,j),j=1,3),i=1,3),((array2(i,j),j=1,3),i=1,3)
```

"advance='no'" is necessary only if you use 2 read statements instead of 1 (and only on the first READ). But this works only with explicit format ...

Reading a file by column is not so obvious, especially because reading a file is usually an expensive task. I suggest you read the file in a larger table and then you distribute the values into your two arrays. For instance :

```
real :: table(5,5)
integer :: i,j,ii,jj,k
..
read(12,*) ((table(i,j),j=1,5),i=1,5)
k=0
do j=1,3
   do i=1,3
      k=k+1
      jj=(k-1)/5+1
      ii=k-(jj-1)*5
      array1(i,j)=table(ii,jj)
   enddo
enddo
do j=1,3
   do i=1,3
      k=k+1
      jj=(k-1)/5+1
      ii=k-(jj-1)*5
      array2(i,j)=table(ii,jj)
   enddo
enddo
```

(3F4.1) is better than (3F3.1) because each number occupies 4 bytes in fact (3 for the digits and 1 for the space between numbers). But as you see, I have used * which avoids to think about such detail.