# C-Style Array Input FORTRAN

Tags: arrays, input, fortran

Currently, I am learning to use FORTRAN, and the awkwardness of the read/write statement is a bit of an impediment in the code I write. How would I implement something like this:

```
int main(void) {
    size_t length;
    printf("Enter array length: ");
    scanf("%zu", &length);

    int array[length];
    printf("Enter array: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);

    return 0;
 }
```

in FORTRAN? I've read this link: [Read in array data into different sized Fortran arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046322/read-in-array-data-into-different-sized-fortran-arrays). But as a FORTRAN newbie, it's still a little advanced for my understanding. I'd appreciate if someone elaborated on that more here if they pleased, and demonstrated how to apply it to my problem. This is my current FORTRAN code:

```
! Sample program to demonstrate my intent
program main
    integer :: length, i
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: array

    write (*, '(A)', advance='no') "Enter array length: "
    read (*,*) length

    allocate(arrray(length))
    do i=1, length
      read (*,*) array(i)
    end do

    dellocate(array)
end program main
```

Also, is there a way to create a C-style variable length array in FORTRAN? I want to allocate "array" on the stack instead of the heap if possible, without the use of "allocate" and "deallocate" statements.

Lastly, as a FORTRAN newbie, I'd appreciate pointers on writing my code and good websites for FORTRAN reference.

Edit: The point here is to be able to input all of the array elements on one line. However, "read" expects every integer on a separate line.

Comment: Other than starting your loop at `i=0` what is the problem with your attempt?

Comment: @francescalus
That was a typo in my code here but I don't have that in my actual code. I want to be able to input all of the integers on one line: but "read"  expects every integer on a separate line.

Comment: To explain that suggested duplicate (although there may be a better one): you are reading each element from distinct records/lines.  You want to read the whole array from one record.

Comment: @francescalus: Thank you very much! Do you know if there is there is a notatation for stack-allocated Variable Length Arrays in FORTRAN?

Comment: yes `read(*,*)array` is far more awkward than `for..declaration....scanf..%d.....pointer)..` :-)  Shouldnt the index be `i` in the c code by the way?

Comment: @agentp: Whoops. my bad. You're right.

Comment: Fortran has no concept of stack, but your compiler may (see documentation).  _Automatic objects_ (using `block` constructs in the main program) may do what you want - see perhaps [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21047161) - but it's hard to tell without more detail.  And certainly may be no better.